# Attribute name "X" associated with an element type "Y" must be followed by the ' = ' character

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I am trying to parse an XML file but I keep getting this error when trying to build.

Here is the XML file:

```
<Student Data>
<Student id="11111">
    <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
    <LastName>Edwards</LastName>
    <Address>
        <Street>345 North</Street>
        <City>Brea</City>
        <State>CA</State>
        <Zip>99999</Zip>
        <Phone>(714) 444-4444</Phone>
    </Address>
    <Classes>
        <Class crn="5555">
            <Name>CIS 100</Name>
            <Units>3</Units>
            <Grade>A</Grade>
        </Class>
        <Class crn="7777">
            <Name>CIS 111</Name>
            <Units>4</Units>
            <Grade>B</Grade>        
        </Class>
    </Classes>
</Student>
</Student Data>
```

Comment: Please provide the parsing code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your XML seems to be invalid. Tag names can't contains spaces. Try changing

```
<Student Data>
```

to something like

```
<Student_Data>
```